# Reproduce multiple tracks with ReactAudioPlayer

Tags: javascript, react-native, html5-audio

I succesfully used [react-audio-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player) to reproduce an audio track; now I need to reproduce more than one track, and possibly to reproduce them sequentially (but without autoPlay: I need to start the first one manually and then the following start by themselves). Is it possible to do that?
What I did:

```
<ReactAudioPlayer
     src="https://www.examplelink1.com/example1.mp3"
     controls
/>
```

What I need:

```
<ReactAudioPlayer
     src=["https://www.examplelink1.com/example1.mp3", "https://www.examplelink2.com/example2.mp3"]
     controls
/>
```

Comment: i read the docs, there is an event called onEnded.
you can replace the src and using state when onEnded is trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the docs the src attribute type is "String", so you can't pass an array.

One simple way could be to create a player component for each track, use the onEnded attribute to catch the current endend track and change te app state consequently.

Your state would have a `currentIndex: 0` attribute which is current track's index.
When you map your array of tracks you check if the current element'index of the array equals to `currentIndex` as autoplay attribute value.

Within the `onEnded` callback you increment the index.